# How to use re.split in python but keep the splitting expression?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string

```
a = "Example text 123"
```

which I want to split by the text `text`

```
b = re.split(r"text", a)
```

which gives

```
['Example ', ' 123']
```

but I want to keep the text I used in the regex, so finally I have as result

```
['Example ', 'text 123']
```

I can do that by

```
myresult = "text" + re.split(r"text", a)
```

but maybe there is a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *lookahead* as described in the [Python's re documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) like this:

```py
a = "Example text 123"
re.split(r'(?=text)', a)
# result: ['Example ', 'text 123']
```

This would split on *nothing,* followed by "text".

Comment: And why was the question closed? It is a programming question or not?

Comment: Thanks. Glad I could help. I wouldn't mind deleting my answer to keep SO clean. I'd just like to know :-)

Comment: Yes that other question is more difficult to read, but it is the same question I did not find at first when looking for the same question ...

Comment: @Alex a duplicate. The accepted answer there is in fact very like mine. I understand we don't want the same question over and over again on this site. I'll leave it to you to decide if you want to delete your question. I wouldn't mind.